# Guide to how not to die on hardcore

Tags: diablo-iii

Are there any guides on how not to die on hardcore, preferrably with a given class *(Monk)*
I'm finding it very hard to do, and I sure could use some tips from a long-time hardcore player

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I level up Hardcore heroes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68140/how-should-i-level-up-hardcore-heroes)

Comment: this seems like one of those point in time questions, that isn't a good fit but i cant vote to close.

Comment: As I said in the answer to the above-linked question, the answer can be summed up in one word: "patience".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watch a lot of content from Forcestrategygaming, especially via youtube and he just started a [Hardcore run series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEzqZsmZ8P0) and elaborates on the pros and cons of gear etc.

The best part is that you can watch him playing so you see how to react to big packs and lure champions out. It's really worth watching even if it's not your specific class (he is playing a mage atm).

Specificly for the monk I found two short guides :[diablo3monksguide](http://diablo3monksguide.com/monks-in-hardcore/) and [mydiablolevlingguide](http://www.mydiablo3levelingguide.com/diablo-3-leveling-guide/diablo-3-monk-hardcore-guide)

Answer (score 0):

1) When in doubt, run.
2) Remember that you don't have to kill everything.  In Diablo II, if you saw certain combinations of monster properties, you simply did not fight it.